# How to order facets when using the Seaborn objects interface

Tags: python, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

I am trying to order facets in a plot produced by the [`seaborn` objects interface](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html).

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset("iris")
df["species"] = df["species"].astype("category")
df["species"] = df["species"].cat.codes
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
df["subset"] = rng.choice(['A','B','C'], len(df), replace=True) 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6.4 * 2.0, 4.8 * 2.0))

_ = (
    so.Plot(df, x="sepal_length", y="sepal_width")
    .facet(row="species", col="subset")
    .add(so.Dot())
    .on(fig)
    .plot()
)
```

[image: A plot with facets row-wise and column-wise. The columns are, left to right--C, B, A--and the rows are, top to bottom--0, 1, 2.]

However, if `col_order` or `row_order` are passed as parameters to the `.facet()` line an "unexpected keyword argument" `TypeError` is raised.

```py
_ = (
    so.Plot(df, x="sepal_length", y="sepal_width")
    .facet(
        row="species",
        col="subset",
        row_order=['A','C','B'],
        col_order=[0,2,1]
    )
    .add(so.Dot())
    .on(fig)
    .plot()
)
```

```
TypeError: Plot.facet() got an unexpected keyword argument 'row_order'
```

How should facets be ordered when using the `seaborn.objects` interface?

Note that this question is very similar to ["Seaborn ordering of facets"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541776/seaborn-ordering-of-facets) which is the same question when the plot is generated using `seaborn` but not the `seaborn.objects` module.

Ideally, an answer should also work when using the `wrap` parameter of `facet()` in the `seaborn.objects` interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Plot.facet`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Plot.facet.html) has a single `order` parameter. When only `col` or `row` are used a single list can be passed and it will be used by the appropriate variable. When both `col` and `row` are used, `order` can be a dictionary with `col`/`row` keys:

```
(
    so.Plot(df, x="sepal_length", y="sepal_width")
    .facet(row="species", col="subset", order={"row": [2, 1, 0], "col": ["A", "B", "C"]})
    .add(so.Dot())
    .layout(size=(6.4 * 2, 4.8 * 2))
)
```